# Using an array of indices for `values_at` method's selectors

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm looking to return elements of an array with the indices in another array. For example:

```
array = ["h", "y", "R", "X", "y", "u", "w", "o", "q"]
indices_array = [1, 3, 7, 8]
```

Normally I would use:

```
array.values_at(1, 3, 7, 8)
```

I need to do something more like this (because my indices_array is quite long)

```
array.value_at(indices_array) # => ["y", "X", "o", "q"]
```

Comment: How long is `indices` array?  And how long is the array itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [splat operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/):

```
array.values_at(*indices_array)
```

Example output:

```
array = ["h", "y", "R", "X", "y", "u", "w", "o", "q"]
indices_array = [1, 3, 7, 8]
array.values_at(*indices_array)
# => ["y", "X", "o", "q"]
```

Comment: Thank you thomthom :) - I need to get to grips with the splat operator. Definitely a huge hole in my coding ability.

Answer (score 1):

thomthom already gave the right suggestion, but to define the method you wanted,

```
class Array
  def value_at(a)
    values_at(*a)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like overkill to monkey patch `Array` by adding a method which sounds like `values_at` given that internally it still uses splat :-)

Comment: @WandMaker HaHaHa, that's right. But it's what the OP asked.